# Scraped Javascript JSON convert to Python JSON

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I have two scraped strings I need convert to python JSON.
edges and nodes.

```
edges = "[{from: '0000000097', to: '0458923133', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0422391349', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0546879961', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0437118919', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0471835219', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0480049733', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0567887488', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0888866824', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0444466470', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0448792769', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0449758613', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0816961219', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0461147797', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0420238939', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0472619434', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0448126736', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0466829326', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0456272657', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0477675114', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0443725609', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0480737938', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0880217293', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0810322657', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0432965537', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0473258347', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0836191765', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0431385922', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0440358719', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0451797492', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0668597541', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0457288682', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0560813814', title: 'out' }]"
nodes = "[{id: '0000000097' , shape: 'star', color: {background:'#F03967', border:'#713E7F',highlight:{background:'red',border:'black'}} , value: 15, label: 'M-DES' },{id: '0458923133' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'SPEED INVEST' },{id: '0422391349' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ELECTRICITEITSWERKEN DECAIGNY FREDDY, AFGEKORT : E.D.F.' },{id: '0546879961' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OSTERIA AGRICOLA TOSCANA BELGIO' },{id: '0437118919' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'IMMOBILIERE DU BOIS D ARPES' },{id: '0471835219' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'EXCELLENCE CONSULTING' },{id: '0480049733' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'JOVEGI' },{id: '0567887488' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'CONINGS ROUMANS DAKWERKEN' },{id: '0888866824' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ONDERNEMERSCENTRUM RONSE' },{id: '0444466470' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'TRANSFOTEC' },{id: '0448792769' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DECAB' },{id: '0449758613' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COMAN' },{id: '0816961219' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ARJULO' },{id: '0461147797' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COUNTRYWIDE TRADING AND MANAGEMENT SERVICES' },{id: '0420238939' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GODEFROOT' },{id: '0472619434' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'PRO USED COMPUTERS, AFGEKORT : PUC' },{id: '0448126736' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'VERCAM INVEST' },{id: '0466829326' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'FINANCE en MANAGEMENT INTERNATIONAL' },{id: '0456272657' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COLORS PRODUCTIONS' },{id: '0477675114' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OXYA CONSULTING BENELUX' },{id: '0443725609' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'KNOOPS COOLING' },{id: '0480737938' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OFFICINALL' },{id: '0880217293' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DIENSTENFIRMA BALDEMO' },{id: '0810322657' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'B INVEST' },{id: '0432965537' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'INGENIEURSBUREAU NORBERT PROVOOST' },{id: '0473258347' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'VON GESSENECK GROUP' },{id: '0836191765' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'BOLCKMANS VASTGOED GROEP' },{id: '0431385922' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GENERAL MANAGEMENT OFFICE, EN ABREGE : G.M.O.' },{id: '0440358719' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GROEP DILLEN' },{id: '0451797492' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DEBOFIN' },{id: '0668597541' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'FRAG INVEST' },{id: '0457288682' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ECKERT en ZIEGLER BEBIG' }] "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's javascript object, so calling directly `json.loads` will not work. One *"hacky"* way is to convert all `'` to `"` and quote dict keys:

```
import re
import json

edges = "[{from: '0000000097', to: '0458923133', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0422391349', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0546879961', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0437118919', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0471835219', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0480049733', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0567887488', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0888866824', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0444466470', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0448792769', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0449758613', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0816961219', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0461147797', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0420238939', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0472619434', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0448126736', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0466829326', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0456272657', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0477675114', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0443725609', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0480737938', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0880217293', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0810322657', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0432965537', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0473258347', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0836191765', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0431385922', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0440358719', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0451797492', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0668597541', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0457288682', title: 'out' },{from: '0000000097', to: '0560813814', title: 'out' }]"
nodes = "[{id: '0000000097' , shape: 'star', color: {background:'#F03967', border:'#713E7F',highlight:{background:'red',border:'black'}} , value: 15, label: 'M-DES' },{id: '0458923133' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'SPEED INVEST' },{id: '0422391349' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ELECTRICITEITSWERKEN DECAIGNY FREDDY, AFGEKORT : E.D.F.' },{id: '0546879961' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OSTERIA AGRICOLA TOSCANA BELGIO' },{id: '0437118919' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'IMMOBILIERE DU BOIS D ARPES' },{id: '0471835219' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'EXCELLENCE CONSULTING' },{id: '0480049733' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'JOVEGI' },{id: '0567887488' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'CONINGS ROUMANS DAKWERKEN' },{id: '0888866824' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ONDERNEMERSCENTRUM RONSE' },{id: '0444466470' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'TRANSFOTEC' },{id: '0448792769' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DECAB' },{id: '0449758613' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COMAN' },{id: '0816961219' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ARJULO' },{id: '0461147797' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COUNTRYWIDE TRADING AND MANAGEMENT SERVICES' },{id: '0420238939' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GODEFROOT' },{id: '0472619434' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'PRO USED COMPUTERS, AFGEKORT : PUC' },{id: '0448126736' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'VERCAM INVEST' },{id: '0466829326' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'FINANCE en MANAGEMENT INTERNATIONAL' },{id: '0456272657' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'COLORS PRODUCTIONS' },{id: '0477675114' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OXYA CONSULTING BENELUX' },{id: '0443725609' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'KNOOPS COOLING' },{id: '0480737938' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'OFFICINALL' },{id: '0880217293' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DIENSTENFIRMA BALDEMO' },{id: '0810322657' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'B INVEST' },{id: '0432965537' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'INGENIEURSBUREAU NORBERT PROVOOST' },{id: '0473258347' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'VON GESSENECK GROUP' },{id: '0836191765' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'BOLCKMANS VASTGOED GROEP' },{id: '0431385922' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GENERAL MANAGEMENT OFFICE, EN ABREGE : G.M.O.' },{id: '0440358719' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'GROEP DILLEN' },{id: '0451797492' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'DEBOFIN' },{id: '0668597541' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'FRAG INVEST' },{id: '0457288682' , shape: 'diamond', color: '#d6a4f5' , value: 10, label: 'ECKERT en ZIEGLER BEBIG' }] "

edges = re.sub(r"([a-z]+):", r'"\1":', edges.replace("'", '"'))
nodes = re.sub(r"([a-z]+):", r'"\1":', nodes.replace("'", '"'))

edges = json.loads(edges)
nodes = json.loads(nodes)

# pretty print    
print(json.dumps(edges, indent=4))
print(json.dumps(nodes, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0458923133",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0422391349",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0546879961",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0437118919",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0471835219",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0480049733",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0567887488",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0888866824",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0444466470",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0448792769",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0449758613",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0816961219",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0461147797",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0420238939",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0472619434",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0448126736",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0466829326",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0456272657",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0477675114",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0443725609",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0480737938",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0880217293",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0810322657",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0432965537",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0473258347",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0836191765",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0431385922",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0440358719",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0451797492",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0668597541",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0457288682",
        "title": "out"
    },
    {
        "from": "0000000097",
        "to": "0560813814",
        "title": "out"
    }
]
[
    {
        "id": "0000000097",
        "shape": "star",
        "color": {
            "background": "#F03967",
            "border": "#713E7F",
            "highlight": {
                "background": "red",
                "border": "black"
            }
        },
        "value": 15,
        "label": "M-DES"
    },
    {
        "id": "0458923133",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "SPEED INVEST"
    },
    {
        "id": "0422391349",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "ELECTRICITEITSWERKEN DECAIGNY FREDDY, AFGEKORT : E.D.F."
    },
    {
        "id": "0546879961",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "OSTERIA AGRICOLA TOSCANA BELGIO"
    },
    {
        "id": "0437118919",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "IMMOBILIERE DU BOIS D ARPES"
    },
    {
        "id": "0471835219",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "EXCELLENCE CONSULTING"
    },
    {
        "id": "0480049733",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "JOVEGI"
    },
    {
        "id": "0567887488",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "CONINGS ROUMANS DAKWERKEN"
    },
    {
        "id": "0888866824",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "ONDERNEMERSCENTRUM RONSE"
    },
    {
        "id": "0444466470",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "TRANSFOTEC"
    },
    {
        "id": "0448792769",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "DECAB"
    },
    {
        "id": "0449758613",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "COMAN"
    },
    {
        "id": "0816961219",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "ARJULO"
    },
    {
        "id": "0461147797",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "COUNTRYWIDE TRADING AND MANAGEMENT SERVICES"
    },
    {
        "id": "0420238939",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "GODEFROOT"
    },
    {
        "id": "0472619434",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "PRO USED COMPUTERS, AFGEKORT : PUC"
    },
    {
        "id": "0448126736",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "VERCAM INVEST"
    },
    {
        "id": "0466829326",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "FINANCE en MANAGEMENT INTERNATIONAL"
    },
    {
        "id": "0456272657",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "COLORS PRODUCTIONS"
    },
    {
        "id": "0477675114",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "OXYA CONSULTING BENELUX"
    },
    {
        "id": "0443725609",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "KNOOPS COOLING"
    },
    {
        "id": "0480737938",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "OFFICINALL"
    },
    {
        "id": "0880217293",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "DIENSTENFIRMA BALDEMO"
    },
    {
        "id": "0810322657",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "B INVEST"
    },
    {
        "id": "0432965537",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "INGENIEURSBUREAU NORBERT PROVOOST"
    },
    {
        "id": "0473258347",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "VON GESSENECK GROUP"
    },
    {
        "id": "0836191765",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "BOLCKMANS VASTGOED GROEP"
    },
    {
        "id": "0431385922",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "GENERAL MANAGEMENT OFFICE, EN ABREGE : G.M.O."
    },
    {
        "id": "0440358719",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "GROEP DILLEN"
    },
    {
        "id": "0451797492",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "DEBOFIN"
    },
    {
        "id": "0668597541",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "FRAG INVEST"
    },
    {
        "id": "0457288682",
        "shape": "diamond",
        "color": "#d6a4f5",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "ECKERT en ZIEGLER BEBIG"
    }
]
```